# What query do I run to select the HIGHEST value for EACH group of values in an SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of `bids` (like an eBay bids, for example):

```
bid_id | bid_from_user | bid_for_auction | bid_price
1      | 150           | 1               | 20
2      | 453           | 1               | 30
3      | 42            | 1               | 50
4      | 12            | 2               | 12
5      | 60            | 2               | 20
```

I need to select each `bid_for_auction` only **once** with its highest current bid, so my result should look like this:

```
bid_for_auction | bid_price
1               | 50
2               | 20
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT bid_for_auction, MAX(bid_price) AS bid_price
FROM bids GROUP BY bid_for_auction;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
 `bid_for_auction`,
 MAX(`bid_price`)
FROM `bids`
GROUP BY `bid_for_auction`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT bid_for_auction, MAX(bid_price)
FROM bids
GROUP BY bid_for_auction
```

Comment: Why did you add `bid_price` in `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT bid_for_auction,MAX(bid_price) FROM bids GROUP BY bid_for_auction